# Renaming Python modules that use compiled code

Tags: python, cpython, python-wheel

Is there a way to rename a Python module that includes compiled code?

I'm attempting to rename Python modules, to accommodate multiple installed versions. (To deal with circular deps in a package manager) I'm parsing .py files, and renaming import statements in the renamed module, and lib that calls it. This works when the renamed module uses purely Python code. I'm running into this with a library (`.so` in this case running Linux)

```py
 File "mtrand.pyx", line 1, in init numpy.random.mtrand
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.random.common'
```

This indicates we need to edit the imported name in `mtrand.pyx`, which doesn't exist in the unpacked wheel. A file named *mtrand.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so* does.

Is this insolvable without recompiling the source, or is there a way to do this? The `.pyx` file that needs to be modified exists [on the lib's github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand.pyx), but not the unpacked wheel.

Comment: This is the clearest example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) I have ever seen. If you need to modify sources of some code to make it run it means your installations are broken. Instead of breaking the code you should find a way to make the different installations work correctly. I don't know: use virtual envs one for each program to have the correct module versions for each program. Obviously without any information about the actual issue nobody can really help you in this regard.

Comment: I'm almost done building a package manager, and I'd like to resolve "unresolvable" dep graphs by installing multiple versions of the same package.

Comment: [Explanation of why you'd do this](https://stephencoakley.com/2019/04/24/how-rust-solved-dependency-hell)

Comment: As long as only relative imports are used you could create symbolic links, but as soon as there is an absolute import, you will need to change the so-file. If the new name is shorter (or at least not longer) than the old, you probably could get away with manipulating so-binary without recompiling (at least for cython-extensions) - but this is probably too much to be a good solution!

Comment: You don't need any name mangling. Just copy the specific version of the library undder your package and use a relative import to include the library from there. The relative import also ensures that the name is unique in `sys.modules` (since there you use the "dotted name"). *If* the library is written correctly (i.e. it should always use relative imports to import submodules etc) then this should work out of the box. If the library is written incorrectly (i.e. using absolute imports) then you are out of luck and you should fork the library and fix it.

Comment: This would solve the problem. Here's what I've attempted: Moving the sub-package into the folder of the package calling it. Rename calls to it from the parent as such: `from numpy import *` to `from .numpy import *`. I recieve the following error: `ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.
>>> 
`. Is there a way around this?